# Dovecot certicate per domains

Tags: ssl-certificate, email-server, dovecot, debian-stretch

I have multiple domain on my mail server (postfix + dovecot) and I want to assign specific cerificate per domains.

Assuming to the dovecot documentation, I've tried this configuration :

```
local_name smtp.domain1.com {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/domain1.com-cert.pem
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/domain1.com-privkey.key
  ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/domain1.com-chain.pem
}

local_name smtp.domain2.com {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/smtp.domain2.com-cert.pem
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/smtp.domain2.com-privkey.key
  ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/smtp.domain2.com-chain.pem
}
```

But it doesn't work. This error is returned when I try to connect to the webmail (roundcube) :

```
Apr 22 22:36:06 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
Apr 22 22:36:06 localhost dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
```

When I try with openssl s_client :

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1524436845
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Without local_name (just 1 set of certificates), all works fine.

What's wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: Just look at your error: 
# Apr 22 22:36:06 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Your file seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I add to dovecot.conf the line :

```
!include /etc/dovecot/conf.d/*.conf
```

at the end & delete

```
ssl_cert = </path/to/cert.pem
ssl_key =</path/to/key.pem
ssl_protocols = !SSLv3
```

(after uncomment same line in 10-ssl.conf)

and it's works now